# Забрать автоматически все изменения во всех ветках?

Tags: linux, git

О резервном копировании удалённых (remote) репозиториев.

Есть десяток репозиториев, которые нужно автоматически отслеживать и держать на отдельном сервере актуальную копию чисто "на всякий случай".

Как это сделать проще всего? Просто поставить в crontab строчку `git pull` или нужно ещё какие-нибудь хитрые ключики прописать?

История коммитов линейная, `push -f` организационно запрещён.

Comment: Просто забирайте все файлы из скрытых директорий .git. Так удобней, скромнее и надёжней.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич это разные сервера географически и нет к ним доступа. Так бы я действительно мог rsync'ом забрать все файлы и делов-то.

Comment: если уже пулом забираете, то в любом случае делайте резервную копию забранного. Несколько лет назад уже был случай, когда форсированно запушили, удалили репозиторий и все это "пулом забекапили" - то есть, потеряли.

Comment: Утилита `repo` из Android умеет это всё делать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В принципе достаточно `git fetch`, чтобы забрать все изменения из всех веток. Но этого недостаточно для защиты от удаления веток и `push -f`.

Пока на ум приходит радикальный метод: после `fetch` вешать тег на каждую ветку `origin/...`. Так она навечно останется referenced в бэкапном репозитории.

Comment: Если запретить GC, то в индексе на сервере всё будет.